# Invalid object name / column after re-opening

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get into SQL using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I've added a database and I want to make a query:

[image: New Query]

This works and I can execute the code, but after I saved my query and closed the program it doesn't work anymore when I open the program and try to execute the query again. It can't find the terms I'm relating to:

[image: Lots of errors]

I don't know why this occurs or how I can solve it, it seems that the connection between the query and the database is gone... Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't post images. Post your raw text sql code here. Also, for your question you need to show the structure of the table tblOrders so we can se what it is wrong.

Comment: The database you're running the query against is master, not your own database. The database selection box is in the toolbar, for some reason disabled though.

Comment: I believe the database selection box is disabled when the query editing pane doesn't have focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add before your query the name of your database:

```
USE dbArtemi

GO

SELECT Naam
FROM tblklaten
WHERE klatenummer =
    (SELECT DISTINCT klatnummer FROM tblorders where (orderID = 11013));
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to execute the query against the `master` database but that's not where your tables are. Three ways to handle this:

- Use the drop-down in the toolbar to switch to the `dbArtemis` database
- Fully-qualify your table names. `dbArtemis.dbo.Klantnummer` for example
- Execute `use dbArtemis;` in your query window before the query itself.